# .NET Windows form application shutdown unexcpectedly

Tags: .net, vb.net, telerik, raddocking

Currently, I'm experiencing a problem with mine VB.net application. 
The thing is that one supplier of a specific software that we use is causing some kind of incompatibility issue with our system.
When I install our supplier's software, our VB.net application just shutdowns unexpectedly. It loads the first login screen and then when I load the main form it just opens and then closes in sequence. If I uninstall the supplier application the problem stops.

It only happens when I'm not debugging. When I start the application in debug mode the error does not occur. I've managed to discover the control that is causing the incompatibility but I could not find a way of avoiding this error without removing the control. The component is a Telerik.WinControls.UI.Docking.RadDock used in an MDI form.

Do you guys experienced something like that?
Why the problem only occurs when I'm not debugging?

**--EDIT--**

I've created logging routines at ApplicationEvents.vb to discover if it is crashing (UnhandledException) or just shutting down (Shutdown method). The application simply shuts down, it doesn't throw any exception.
I've looked the system event viewer and there isn't any log or info about the problem.
When I go to the .designer of the form with the RadDock and remove the line `Me.Controls.Add(Me.RadDock1)` the software runs fine without closing. The problem is that I need this component, I can't simply remove it.

Comment: Have you looked in the systems Event Viewer to find out what is actually causing the crash? The system usually logs things like different version dll issues, .NET version issues, crashes etc to help users determine faults. This would be a good place to start and may give you a few leads as to how to fix the problem.

Comment: Which .Net version is this? Is that Telerik control loaded from the GAC?

Comment: @CodexNZ Yes, I've looked the event viewer and there is no log about the unexpected shutdown. I've created logging routines in ApplicationEvents.vb and the application calls the Shutdown method. It does not pass through the UnhandledException method, looks to me like a "friendly" shutdown.

Comment: @rene I'm using .NET framework 4. But I didn't understood the GAC part, how do I tell if its being loaded from the GAC or not?

Comment: Is the Telerik assembly reference set as copy local = true? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c(v=vs.100).aspx if it is not,  make sure it is and re-test.

Comment: @rene thanks for the repply, it is already copy local = true, the error persists.